# PowerShell: How can I add a new column with values to the Get-Service Output?

Tags: powershell

I try to add a new column to the `Get-Service` Output. The solutions I found till now, add the column, but it isn't possible to add more than one value to it. I save the Output in an Array for example like this:

```
$b =  @() 

$b += Get-Service wuauserv
```

Do you know, how I can change the normal ouput:

```
Status        Name       DisplayName                           
- - - -    - - - --     - - -  --  - - - -                   
Running     wuauserv     Windows Update                        
Running     sysmain      Superfetch
```

to something like this:

```
Status        Name                DisplayName           ComputerName                  
- - - - - - -   - - - - - - - -         - - - - - -  --  - - - - - -                   
Running   wuauserv           Windows Update        Server1                
Running   sysmain            Superfetch                     Server5
```

Hope, anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
$b = @()

$b += Get-Service -ComputerName SERVER1-Name wuauserv
$b += Get-Service -ComputerName SERVER2 -Name sysmain 

$b | Select-Object Status, Name, DisplayName, MachineName
```

If you run the following command:

```
$b | Get-Member
```

It will tell you that there is a `Property` available called `MachineName`. This is the one you can use with the `Select-Object` CmdLet to see the `ComputerName` in the output.

Comment: You're welcome :) Keep exploring and you'll get better at it as you go.

Answer (score 0):

The `ComputerName` is not part of the `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` object returned by the [Get-Service](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113332) cmdlet. Therefore, you have to use an expression within your select statement and obtain the computername (eg. using `$env:computername`):

```
Get-Service wuauserv | select Status, Name, DisplayName, @{l="ComputerName";e={$env:COMPUTERNAME}}
```

**Edit:**
Ah, there is a `MachineName` property which you can use (thanks to Darklite1). So if you want to rename the column, you can use this:

```
Get-Service wuauserv | select Status, Name, DisplayName, @{l="ComputerName";e={$_.MachineName}}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I can add some more details about the server in the same table *happy*